# Get circle rotation on sphere based on mouse position in a plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry, rotation

I'm with this trouble and couldn't find a solution.

I have this white sphere working as a globe and I want to rotate this red line accordingly with the mouse position on the white sphere. This interaction will be in a cartesian base (x, y).
I just need to rotate the red line on Y-axis.
I made it works if you click on the equator, but it goes wrong if I click in a position as the first image.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?
I already tried cartesian to polar formulas and others, but nothing works properly.

I'm doing this on Unity with C#.
This is my code that works with the equator point.

```
Vector3 localPoint = globe.transform.InverseTransformPoint(hit.point);

float relativePoint;
relativePoint = localPoint.x * 2f;

float rotation = Mathf.Acos(relativePoint) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

Vector3 currentRotation = line.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
currentRotation.y = rotation;
line.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
```

Thanks

[image: Scene with two screenshots both with a sphere and a red line around it with different rotations]

Comment: What's wrong about the first image? The drawn X indicates the mouse position correct? To me, the image shows that the ring has been rotated around the Y so that it intersects the clicked position.  This question would be improved if you were to show what your desired outcome is.

Comment: The first image is what I want as a result. But now, when I click on that point, the red line stays a little bit to the left.